# how to select data from one table and check condition from other table mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

[See Attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjrkF.png)

I'm creating a website in which a registered user can see a post only once.i have used a DB table (viewed posts) in which i save user id  of the logged in user and post id of the post he viewed . i want to show only those posts to user which he has not seen yet from the (post) table. please help me how i can do this . i have tried left joint etc but none of them works well

i also tried this one but it not works

```
select * from post, viewed_post 
where post.p_id !=viewed_post.p_id 
  AND viewed_post.u_id!='$logged_in_user_id';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `NOT IN` operator:

```
select * from post
WHERE post.p_id NOT IN (
    SELECT p_id
    FROM viewed_post
    WHERE user_id = '$logged_in_user_id'
)
```